# How to use $1 inside the path to a folder

Tags: shell-script, grep

I'm fairly new to linux scripting and apologize if this has been asked (did search quite a bit before posting).

I'm creating a simple script to check if certain letter combinations are occurring inside a backup file. The path to these files are device dependent and there are MANY of them so I have a list of the ones I need to check inside a text file.

What I would like to do, is `cat` the file and insert the name of the device inside the path to that devices folder and then check the latest backup file. e.g.

```
cat devicelist.txt  | grep A[BCD] /folder1/folder2/$1/latest
```

This gives me the error: `/latest: No such file or directory`

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then you could use `xargs` e.g.

```
cat devicelist.txt | xargs -d'\n' -I{} echo grep 'A[BCD]' "/folder1/folder2/{}/latest"
```

or (reading the file directly)

```
xargs -a devicelist.txt -d'\n' -I{} echo grep 'A[BCD]' "/folder1/folder2/{}/latest"
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing what you want.

See `man xargs` for further information and a complete list of available options for your platform.

Answer (score 0):

$1 means parameter (first) passed to the script

so you can use

```
#!/bin/bash
grep A[BCD] /folder1/folder2/"$1"/latest
```

do not cat | grep when useless :) 
"$1" permit to preserve the variable content

```
-bash-4.4$ mkdir test
-bash-4.4$ mkdir -p test/folder/a/latest
-bash-4.4$ cat > t.sh
#!/bin/sh
grep A[BCD] test/folder/"$1"/latest/toto
-bash-4.4$ chmod u+x t.sh
-bash-4.4$ echo ABCD > test/folder/a/latest/toto
-bash-4.4$ ./t.sh b
grep: test/folder/b/latest/toto: No such file or directory
-bash-4.4$ ./t.sh a
ABCD
-bash-4.4$ rm t.sh
-bash-4.4$ rm -rf test
-bash-4.4$
```

you may also preserve script to $1 values that do not exists if you want to avoid the error message from grep when folder path is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
grep 'A[BCD]' "/folder1/folder2/$1/latest" <devicelist.txt
```

in a script which you have called with an argument.

If you want to simulate the same behaviour in the shell then you have to do this before:

```
set -- foo
```

Then `$1` becomes `foo`.